# Can the IMF Special Drawing Rights be used to combat the need for negative interest rates in order to fiscally stimulate the global economy?

Tags: economy, international-law, international, international-monetary-fund

Can the IMF Special Drawing Rights be used to combat the need for negative interest rates in order to fiscally stimulate the global economy? I am wondering if the U.S. can use the IMF in order to stimulate the global economy thereby gaining more fiscal tools to its arsenal before having to use the dreaded negative interest rate. Is this possible or are there political rules or laws that prevents the U.S. from doing so?